# Class of data.table column

Tags: r, data.table

I'd like to know how to ascertain the class of a column in a data.table `dt` given a character vector `w`.

Reproducible example:

```
dt <- data.table(matrix(1:10, 2))
w <- "V1"
```

When you specify a column by name directly, it returns the vector so that you can get its class:

```
> dt[,V1]
[1] 1 2
> class(dt[,V1])
[1] "integer"
```

Specify it as a character vector, however, and it instead returns a one-column data.table:

```
> dt[,w,with=FALSE]
   V1
1:  1
2:  2
> class(dt[,w,with=FALSE])
[1] "data.table" "data.frame"
```

I've sort of munged my way to the following solution, but surely there's a better way:

```
dt[,eval(parse(text=paste0("class(",w,")")))]
```

So two questions:

1. Is there a better (more concise) to get the class of a single column (withoout giving up the speed that the above solution gains by evaluating the call to `class` in the environment of the data.table?
2. Is there a way to get a vector of the classes of all columns, analagous to `sapply( myDataFrame, class)` ?

Comment: hee hee you know better than to admit to using "eval(parse("  :-)

Comment: @CarlWitthoft I have no shame :-)

Answer (score 26, accepted):

These seem to work in the way you want:

1. `class(dt[[w]])`
2. `sapply(dt,class)`

Also, doing 2 and then subsetting works for 1: `sapply(dt,class)[w]`.

Comment: Much simpler, thanks.  The expressions way seemed more `data.table`-like, so I assumed it would be faster, but timing shows that even on a big table it's slower (probably because of the overhead of building the call--we're talking microseconds).

Comment: +1 Yes we like `[[` and `$` on `data.table` (they don't copy).

Comment: Also worth noting; `data.table` only makes a shallow copy of `dt` when `sapply` / `lapply` is called, thanks to the implementation of `as.list.data.table`. In the case of `data.frame`s, copies are made.