# Change data.table values in one column for multiple rows

Tags: r, data.table

I am trying to change the values of one column for specific rows in a data.table. This works when I do a vector scan but not when I do a binary search.

```
dtData <- data.table(TickerId = c(1,2,3,4,5), DateTime = c(1,2,3,4,5), Close =     c(100,200,300,400,500), key=c('TickerId', 'DateTime'))
dtQuery <- data.table(TickerId = c(1,4), DateTime = c(1,4))

#Binary search doesn't work - both changed rows now contain 101
dtData[dtQuery, Close:=c(101,401)]

#Vector scan works
dtData[TickerId %in% c(1,4) & DateTime %in% c(1,4), Close:=c(101,401)]
```

Could someone point out why this might be the case?

Also what would be the best (fastest) way to change values like this in a large data.table?

Thank you.

Comment: this happens because of a hidden `by-without-by`; eventually `by-without-by` will be made explicit (and modifiable) so this issue will go away - [FR #2696](https://r-forge.r-project.org/tracker/index.php?func=detail&aid=2696&group_id=240&atid=978); for now I think Wolfgang's answer is the way to go (oh didn't realize *you* are Wolfgang:))

Comment: Your vector scan looks very fragile. What happens if you see a pair (4,1) or if you see the (4,4) before the (1,1)?

Comment: @Frank, agreed. That is why I wanted to have some better solution :)

Comment: Cool cool. I had thought you were just looking for a speed-up.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Does this work?

```
dtQuery[,newClose:=c(101,401)]
dtData[dtQuery,Close:=newClose]
```

If so, it is *far* better than your vector scan, and not just because of speed. The vector scan looks very fragile. With it, what happens if you see a pair (4,1) or if you see the (4,4) before the (1,1)?

Comment: Yes, this works and is better than having a separate vector. Great stuff. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Note the different results from

```
dtData[dtQuery, Close]
#    TickerId DateTime Close
# 1:        1        1   100
# 2:        4        4   400

dtData[TickerId %in% c(1,4) & DateTime %in% c(1,4), Close]
# [1] 100 400
```

So in order to use binary search, you have to select the Close column

```
dtData[dtQuery, ][, Close]
```

However, assignement does not work in compound queries.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. So I guess you are saying there is no "direct" way of assigning new values with a binary search.

Comment: As far as I know... I'm not the `data.table` expert, but as far as I can tell there isn't.

Comment: Fyi, the [,Close] can also be done with [['Close']] and $Close. See Matt Dowle's comment here (he's the author of data.table): http://stackoverflow.com/a/18835813/1191259 Also, it's okay to skip the comma if only using the first argument, like dtData[dtQuery]

Answer (score 1):

Inspired by shadow's answer, I found an "non compound" way that seems to work. First get the row numbers with a binary search, then update the data.table using the found row numbers.

```
dtIndex <- dtData[dtQuery, .I]
dtData[dtIndex$".I", Close:=c(101,401)]
```

Any better ideas for a fast update?

Comment: If you can, it would be better to write the right-hand side as a formula instead of a vector, I think, like `.I*100L+1L` if that applies.

Comment: Understood and agreed. However the right hand side in my problem is not a formulaic (this was just my quick reproducible example code), so this is not an option.