# Merge two data frames with non-unique keys

Tags: r, data.table

I want to select the rows of data1 if the value of the first column exists in data2:

```
data1<-data.table(a=c(1,2,3,1),b=c(1,4,6,3))
data2<-data.table(a=c(1,3,1,5,6))


Desired output:
a b 
1 1 
3 6 
1 3
```

The merge does not work since the keys are not unique, any other idea?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's an approach without joins:

```
> unique(data1[a %in% data2[,a],])
   a b
1: 1 1
2: 3 6
3: 1 3
```

Comment: Mmm on my system it is - possibly this changed with a newer version of `data.table`? I get 5 rows without `unique`.

Comment: I am using the devel version, so probably it is different.

Comment: Okay, I'm still on 1.9.4.

Comment: Do you think there will be some performance difference by using `[[`.. i.e. `data1[a %in%data2[['a']]]`

Comment: It's possible - may be worthwhile to benchmark a larger data set.

Comment: @akrun I suspect `[[` or `$` is preferred based on (1) the overhead of `[` and (2) Matt Dowle saying they're good because they don't copy http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18835576/class-of-data-table-column/18835813#comment27788236_18835813

Answer (score 4):

We can create a sequence column ('ind') in each of the datasets for the 'a' column and 'join' after setting the key column as 'a' and 'ind'

```
data1[, ind:=1:.N, a]
data2[, ind:= 1:.N, a]
setkey(data1, a, ind)[data2, nomatch=0][, ind:=NULL]
#   a b
#1: 1 1
#2: 3 6
#3: 1 3
```